# What is this ... electrical bike's setup? Is there a particular brand or model name for this? how to replace its battery?

Tags: electric-bike, used-bike, battery, electric-power

[image]

Just bought it from someone, interested to get it fixed. he said it just needs to replace battery, I doubt it (after numerous experience with asking the sellers "what is wrong with the bike" and ends up there is always more things  are wrong). So I wonder, if this is actually a working electric bike at all... and where ahd how exactly I replace its battery? I do not see one lol Did google some video but none like this.

Comment: The battery is in the metal box under the rack.  This is a fairly common setup for e-bikes.  (And it looks like a manufacturer-produced setup to me, though a very old one, likely with lead-acid or ni-cad batteries that are hard to find anymore.)

Comment: I had a similar motor setup.  It uses a very short chain loop between the motor and the LEFT side of the rear wheel hub.  So you need a special wheel.  Also, so little chain means it wears quicker, so you should use 1/8" chain for the increased durability.

Comment: @ezeewei  please peel off the top plate (the four bolts visible in your picture)  and take a photo of whatever's inside.   Also, do you have the wall-charger for this system?  Please photograph that and any labels on it.   And a photo of the batteries if you can get them out, (probably screwed down with a retaining strap inside that case.)

Comment: @Criggie did yours have a rear derailleur? Presumably not if you could use 1/8" chain. Could you use a flip-flop hub with the freewheel on the pdeal drive side and the fixed on the electric side?

Comment: @ChrisH that's exactly what mine had - a freewheeling sprocket (but reversed) on the left hand side of the hub, and a 100% normal derailleur transmission on the right hand side of the hub.  The 1/8"  chain was only 15-18 links long and connected the motor to the wheel hub.  It still had normal 3/32" chain on the right for the transmission.

Comment: @Ezeewei consider protecting that wiring better too - its not well-protected and is exposed to damage.  The motor is really low, and it sticks out the left hand side of the bike.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks to be an older Currie Electro Drive, they were originally made in 1996 i believe. I don't know much to anything else about them though other than that is one and they exist.

Here is the companies website which offers support options. I would look for a serieal number and call them with questions about battery replacement.

http://www.currietech.com/about.html

Also, i found this random page that sells parts, you may be able to source a battery and spare parts from them as well.

https://electricscooterparts.com/currieelectrodriveelectricbicyclekitparts.html

This looks to be quite similar as far as the motor mount and rack go.

From what i can tell they make a very large battery pack that slides down the side of that rack and connects to those two metal terminals above the bicycles axle (the blue block). You can see them if you follow the second link i listed.

[image]

Comment: As the battery pack is 24V you could in theory make up you own batteries. All you need is 24V, wire them into the terminals, and and some way to mount them on the rack. For testing the motor works, a couple of car batteries would work well.

Comment: @mattnz - If you don't match the technology of the old batteries you risk burning out the controller electronics (or setting fire to the batteries).

Comment: I'm guessing it's a couple of lead-acid batteries in that box. I've ridden a 36V lead-acid e-bike of a similar age; that used that same batteries as small UPSs

Comment: Yeah, the batteries pictured in one of the above links appear to be standard lead-acid batteries of the sort used for emergency lighting, etc.  A local battery distributor such as Batteries Plus would have replacements.